# Matplotlib, there are two seperate sets of numbers on each axes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am plotting 2 data series (obtained from a csv via `pandas`) using matplotlib,
however I have noticed that the resulting plot has the expected numbering on the axes however overlayed onto both axes is additional numbering (from 0 to 1.0) which appears to come from nowhere (see attached image). My pandas `DataFrame` does not contain any `Series` which corresponds to this [0, 1.0] numbering on the axes.

My code is as follows

```
def create_plot(data: pd.DataFrame, figure, plotIndex):
    ax = figure.add_subplot(*plotIndex)
    ax.plot(data.col1, data.col2, color="#39915d", marker="o")
    return figure

files = "file1",
figure, _ = plt.subplots(ncols=len(files), nrows=1)
    for i, file in enumerate(files):
        get_file(file)
        create_plot(get_data(file)), figure, (1, len(files), i+1))
plt.show()
```

Where get_data  method returns a `pandas` `DataFrame`.

If anyone has any ideas what is causing this, and how to remedy it, that would be appreciated.

Note: That I am running the python script under WSL (windows subsystem for linux) and using `VcXsrv` in windows so I can display the plot using X11.
[image]

Comment: Any reason you don't use the axes that come with `plt.subplots` ? The error could be in there since you're essentially overlaying axes on top of each other

Comment: Oh that sounds correct, how do I remover the subplot axis then?

Comment: I figured it out fairly quickly, thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @StonedTensor I figured out the issue, i was generating two axes by calling `plt.subplot()` and then also calling `figure.add_subplot` in the `create_plot()` function.

Therefore to fix this issue I just changed the call to `plt.subplot` to `plt.figure()` which does not generate an axis, and I defer creation of an axis to the `figure.add_subplot` call.

Thanks again to @StonedTensor.